# How to Flip or increase VideoRotation

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I have a problem with `SetRecordRotation` in UWP, I was wondering is there a possibility to increase a `setRecordingRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise180Degrees)` to `setRecordingRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise360Degrees)` in case not only to double it or to flip video or mirroring like in Skype.

I am creating an app that the need to record with a preview like in SKYPE, below it's my code any suggestion

```cs
private async Task InitializeCameraAsync()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("InitializeCameraAsync");

    if (mc == null)
    {
        // Attempt to get the back camera if one is available, but use any camera device if not

        var allVideoDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
        //StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("proporties.txt");
        //String timestamp = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
        var cameraDevice = localSettings.Values["camValue"].ToString();

        if (allVideoDevices == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No camera device found!");
            return;
        }

        // Create MediaCapture and its settings
        mc = new MediaCapture();
        var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = allVideoDevices[int.Parse(cameraDevice)].Id };
        await mc.InitializeAsync(settings);
        //CaptureElement.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform { ScaleX = -1 };
        //_isInitialized = true;
        SetResolution();

        DisplayInformation displayInfo = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
        displayInfo.OrientationChanged += DisplayInfo_OrientationChanged;
        DisplayInfo_OrientationChanged(displayInfo, null);


        stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        llmr = await mc.PrepareLowLagRecordToStreamAsync(MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto), stream);
        //mc.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise180Degrees);

        // mc.SetRecordRotation(rotationAngle);
        //CaptureElement.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform()
        //{
        //ScaleX = 1
        //};
        //mc.SetPreviewMirroring(_mirroringPreview);
        //SetPreviewRotationAsync();

    ->  i want it to be VideoRotation.Clockwise360Degrees not instead Clockwise180Degrees is there any way to increas
        mc.SetRecordRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise180Degrees);
        await llmr.StartAsync();
        await llmr.StopAsync();



        CaptureElement.Source = mc;
        CaptureElement.FlowDirection = _mirroringPreview ?  FlowDirection.LeftToRight :  FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
        CaptureStack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        //if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("camValue") == false)
        //{
            //CameraErrorTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        //}
        RecordProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        CaptureGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        CancelButton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        //CaptureElement.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;

        //Prepare low lag recording
        stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        //var encodingProperties = (CaptureElement.Tag as StreamResolution).EncodingProperties;
        var encodingProfile= MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);
        // Calculate rotation angle, taking mirroring into account if necessary
        //var rotationAngle = VideoRotation.Clockwise180Degrees + VideoRotation.Clockwise180Degrees;
        //mc.SetRecordRotation(rotationAngle);
        //var rotationAngle = 360 - ConvertDeviceOrientationToDegrees(GetCameraOrientation());
        //encodingProfile.Video.Properties.Add(RotationKey, mc.SetRecordRotation(rotationAngle));

        llmr = await mc.PrepareLowLagRecordToStreamAsync(encodingProfile, stream);

        await mc.StartPreviewAsync();
    }
    else if (mc != null)
    {
        //if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("camValue") == true)
        //{
        CameraErrorTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things that I would like to call out:

1. Rotating anything 360 degrees is the same as rotating it 0 degrees, which means it will remain unchanged. What you want is to flip it horizontally, to mirror it.
2. Apps like Skype only do this for the user-side preview, not for the stream transmitted to the other endpoint, which remains unchanged. The reason for this is that if the user holds up something like text, the receiver should be able to see it the way it is. Reading mirrored text is a lot harder.

So, even though I said you should do mirroring instead of rotating 360 degrees, in reality you shouldn't do anything at all to the video capture stream in order to provide the best experience.

Finally, to mirror the preview, the easiest way is to use the FlowDirection property of the CaptureElement (for C# or C++), or alternatively use a transform of x:-1 y:1 on the style of the `video` element (for JS):

```
cameraPreview.style.transform = "scale(-1, 1)";
```

or a RenderTransform (for C# or C++). For a reference on how to mirror the preview, you can check out the [CameraStarterKit sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit) on github, which covers C#, C++, JS and VB.